# how to specify when there are no pages left in an infinite scroll with kaminari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2, infinite-scroll

hi am having a problem with infinite scroll functionality, when all the contents have been displayed it still continues to scroll (strange behavior). i am looking for a way to stop the infinite scroll when all contents are displayed...but first i need to know when there no more pages/contents left

here is my code

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
   (function () {
    var page = 1,
    loading = false,
    finish = false;


  function nearBottomOfPage() {
  return $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 200;
  }

  function finish() {
  finish = true;

  }
 $(window).scroll(function () {
 if (loading) {
  return;
 }
 if (nearBottomOfPage() && !finish) {
  loading = true;
  $('#loader').show();
  page++;
  $.ajax({
    url: '/office?page=' + page,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'script',
    success: function () {
      $('#loader').hide();
      loading = false;
    }
   });
  }
 });
 }());
```

i tried this

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
   (function () {
    var page = 1,
    loading = false,
    finish = false;


  function nearBottomOfPage() {
  return $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 200;
  }

  function finish() {
  finish = true;

  }
 $(window).scroll(function () {
 if (loading) {
  return;
 }
 if (nearBottomOfPage() && !finish) {
  loading = true;
  $('#loader').show();
  page++;
  $.ajax({
    url: '/office?page=' + page,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'script',
    success: function () {
      $('#loader').hide();
      loading = false;
    }
   });
      $.error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //Finish scrolling.
    finish();
});
  }
 });
 }());
```

i added the .error function but it still didn't work  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about,

```
$.ajax({
     //calls  
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //Finish scrolling.
        finish();
    });
```

Comment: for some reason the fail/error method isnt fired...any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

When you get a result from your `$.ajax` call, check if you got fewer than the expected number of records (you expect 20 per page, you got 17, for example), then you are at the end of the result set, and you should unset your `$(window).scroll` event, or you should set a flag that causes the event handler to short-circuit.

Comment: how can i use jquery to get number of records gotten from each get method  :(

Comment: You're returning a type of 'script', so you should know how many records you have when you generate that script serverside. If the records are fewer than the expected man, then include code in your returned script to unbind the handler.